# Making table with divs

Tags: html, html-table

I need to do this table in HTML and CSS:

[image: this table]
I can only use `<div>`, not `<table>`.

Comment: using DIVS only not TABLE

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: Why do you build only DIVs, not Table? You need to make this table using table tag. This is not a layout. This is a real data table. Building it using table tag is semantic markup. If you build this table using DIVs, users using screen reader can't understand properly.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do this using CSS style attribute "table", and then setting the class in each div tag.

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTableCell,
.divTableHead {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  color: #013e7f;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">Asistentes</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">Cosistentes</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">1</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">2</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't able to use a table element, I would suggest this:

1. If you want an easy way to do it, you can get the Bootstrap 3 library:
   [Getting Started: Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)
2. Bootstrap has a grid system that automatically divides your content into equal parts across your page.  I would look into using bootstrap as it is very easy to use and prevents writing a lot of the code yourself.
   [Documentation on Grid System in Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

One other note, you can customize what part of the library you want to include so you don't have to use the entire Bootstrap library just for the grid. [Customize your Bootstrap Library](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)